# Prevent multiple logins using command line args, if statement checks, C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, command-line

I am currently writing a login method that keeps track of a logged in user by reading the contents of credentials saved in a text file called "accounts.txt".

The method works fine up to this point however I dont understand how I could make a simple check to prevent multiple logins. I am using command line arguments to input a string that logs in a user.

Example of this when input by command line is "login tom C#password" with "login" being passed as the *command* parameter, "tom" as *param1*, and "C#password" as the *param2*.

Ideally the method should check as an if statement that prevents a double login until the user inputs a "logout" command after "login" has already been used by command line args.

I'm fairly new to c#, any kind of advice is appreciated

```
 protected void login(string command, string param1, string param2) // string command "login" string username, string password
        {
            // login command
            // Needs to check check accounts.txt file for username and password.
            // if username and password exists, provide login message/else failed login
            // NO two logins at the same time until logout command is provided after the first login
            // checks accounts.txt file if username already exists and if there is a match, if not a prompt says login has failed

            var logins = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Files\\accounts.txt");
            if (command == "login")
            {
                if (logins.Any(l => l == string.Format("{0} {1}", param1, param2)))
                    Console.WriteLine("Login {0} ", param1);
                string path1 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path1))
                {
                    sw1.WriteLine("User " + param1 + " logged in");
                }
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: Invaild username or password");
                }

            //checks if more than one user logged in

            if (check for double login command)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: simultaneous login not permitted");
                string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
                using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
                {
                sw2.WriteLine("Login Failed: simultaneous login not permitted");
                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```

logout is a simple method that records if a user has logged out

```
 protected void logout(string command, string param1)
        {
            // remove current username and password from memory
        var logout = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Files\\accounts.txt");
        if (command == "logout")
        {
            if (logout.Any(l => l == string.Format("{0} {1}", param1, param2)))
                Console.WriteLine("Logout {0} ", param1);
            string path1 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path1))
            {
                sw1.WriteLine("User " + param1 + " logged out");
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Logout Failed");

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: add a boolean flag - set it to true when the user logs in, and set it to false when the user logs out. Then, when logging in, check the value of the flag, and if it is true forbid access.

Comment: Do you want avoid multiple login within the same process or do you want avoid it between multiple instances of your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the security issue that represents storing account data in plain text, this is what you should do:

Add a bool property to your class, like this:

```
private bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; set; }
```

And then check for and assign that flag on your login method:

```
var logins = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Files\\accounts.txt");
if (command == "login")
{
    if (IsUserLoggedIn) //check whether someone is logged in
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: simultaneous login not permitted");
        string path2 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
        using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.AppendText(path2))
        {
            sw2.WriteLine("Login Failed: simultaneous login not permitted");
        }
    }
    else if (logins.Any(l => l == string.Format("{0} {1}", param1, param2)))
    {
       IsUserLoggedIn = true; // set the flag so that you know someone has logged in
       Console.WriteLine("Login {0} ", param1);
       string path1 = "C:\\Files\\audit.txt";
       using (StreamWriter sw1 = File.AppendText(path1))
       {
           sw1.WriteLine("User " + param1 + " logged in");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Failed: Invaild username or password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a file will work, but also look at the .Net memory cache. The application can either create its own instance so that multiple logins can be avoided for one instance, or it can use the "default instance" so that multiple logins can be avoided across all instances. Below is a declaration for the default instance:

```
private readonly ObjectCache memCache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

Data can be written to the cache with an expiry time which might be handy if an unhandled exception occurs and the app doesn't logout the user. Use Add, Set, and Get methods to write and read data.

See [ObjectCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true) for additional details.